# Lotusscripts Get rich text field and send Email

Tags: email, lotusscript

I try to coding is sending Rich text field via email , but I find an error that's I think this method for sending email, by following code

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument

    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = w.CurrentDocument
    Set s = New NotesSession
    Set w = New NotesUIWorkspace
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set doc =  New NotesDocument (db)

    doc.sendTo =s.UserName
    doc.Subject = "Employee Information"

    Dim rt As NotesRichTextItem
    Set rt = New NotesRichTextItem ( doc, "Body" )

    'Dim file As Variant  'if I use this code for declare for get value; Error : Type Mismatch
    'Set file = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
    Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem 'if I use this code for declare for get value ; Error : Missing text object
    Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" ) 
    Call rt.AppendRTItem(rtitem)

    doc.Send(False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you don't set the form on the mail document you are creating.

You have some code you don't need, since you don't use uidoc anywhere, no need for that or declaring a NotesUIWorkspace object.
I also recommend that you use better variable names, and not to use extended notation when you set field values in a NotesDocument object.

I suggest that you take a look at the articles here:
http://blog.texasswede.com/how-to-write-better-code-in-notesdomino/

Below is the code that I cleaned up:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim mailDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim mailBody As NotesRichTextItem

    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set mailDoc = New NotesDocument(db)
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form","Memo")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo",session.UserName)
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject","Employee Information")
    Set mailBody = New NotesRichTextItem(mailDoc,"Body" )

    'Dim file As Variant  'if I use this code for declare for get value; Error : Type Mismatch
    'Set file = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
    Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem 'if I use this code for declare for get value ; Error : Missing text object
    Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")   

    Call mailBody.AppendRTItem(rtitem)
    Call mailDoc.Send(False)
End Sub
```

The big question here is where you are getting the rich text field you want to send from? In your original code you are trying to read it from the newly created document (the one I call mailDoc). But that does not make any sense.
Your problem is simply that you are not reading the rich text from anywhere.

If your goal is to send an email, you can use my mail notification class:
http://blog.texasswede.com/updated-mailnotification-class-now-with-html-email-support-and-web-links/

Then your code would look something like this:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim mail As NotesMail
' *** Create a mail
Set mail = New NotesMail()
' Set receipient and subject
mail.MailTo = session.CommonUsername
mail.Subject = "Employee Information"
mail.Principal = "noreply@example.com"
' Create body content from rtitem.
' Yes, I should have added a method in the 
' class to append RichtText to the mail body...
mail.body.AppendRTItem(rtitem)
Call mail.Send()
```

The only thing you have to do is to get the rtitem from somewhere. Since your original code declared a NotesUIWorkSpace object and a NotesUIDocument object, I am guessing you want to read it from the currently open document. Then you just add the following to the beginning of the code:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim thisdoc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem as NotesRichTextItem
Set thisdoc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
Set rtitem = thisdoc.GetFirstItem("Body")
```

Do you also see how much easier it is to read when you use descriptive variable names?

Comment: thank you for your sugeession  @Karl-Henry Martinsson  and sorry about my busy code, I'm a new for Lotus Notes Developer. I will try to follow your suggession. Thank you.

Comment: thank you again for your code . Now it's work but I can't declared "Dim mail As NotesMail
' *** Create a mail
Set mail = New NotesMail()" It's show error Not found this . then My code is Dim rt As NotesRichTextItem
 Set rt = New NotesRichTextItem ( thisdoc, "Body" )
 Call rt.AppendText("Employee No : ")
 Call rt.AppendText(composed)
 It's work , Success for send file in rich text field to Email , thank you very much

Comment: You have to download my custom class. Either put it in a script library and reference it in your agent (recommended, since you can reuse it in other agents in your application) or put the class in the Declarations section.

Comment: I downloaded your custom class , It's work well. That's class can use in NotesMail for sending Email  but i still have problem About Error (Type mismatch) in this code " Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem  Set rtitem = thisdoc.GetFirstItem("Body") '{Body Is my rich text field}
 Messagebox Typename(rtitem) '{TYPE NAME : NOTESRICHTEXTITEM} mail.body.AppendRTItem(rtitem) ' {Type mismatch}

Answer (score 0):

Hi you did not saved the document. Please be aware the Richtext is not available if the document is not saved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggession.